# How to run a shell script on Ubuntu-touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, scripts

I want to run a shell script on my "bq Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu-Edition" phone in the Terminal App and created a shell script in /home/phablet/Documents/sync.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# sync contacts and calendar with OwnCloud
syncevolution owncloud calendar-defaultcalendar
syncevolution --sync slow owncloud contacts
exit 0
```

The script is executable but returns:

```
bash: ./sync.sh: /bin/sh: bad interpreter : Permission denied
```

I'm not sure what interpreter runs on Ubuntu-touch (bash, sh, ??)
and I'm also not sure what rights the default user has.

So what's wrong or missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [a bug in the ubuntu-terminal-app](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-terminal-app/+bug/1325571).

The bug description mentions a workaround:

> It seems to work when I use `bash ./testscript`.

The `./` is optional

Comment: +1. Do you need the ./ ?

Comment: @Tim, as far as I understand the rules, no. It doesn't make lookup in PATH when you give filenames to any command (bash, cat, vi, whatever...).

Answer (score 2):

Whatever it is (a bug or a weird configuration):

```
./yourscript.sh
```

does not work on Ubuntu-touch. The workaround is:

```
bash yourscript.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

After some (preliminary) testing, it appears to me that this is not a bug with the ubuntu-terminal-app, but is instead to do with not being allowed to launch executable files from within the home directory. That's why `bash /path/to/file` worked, but `/path/to/file` didn't, because bash resides in `/bin`.

I have tried running a bash script, a python script, and a hello-world g++ compiled c++ program, all with the executable bit set, and none will run when in a subdirectory of `/home`. None will run, whilst scripts and applications in other subdirectories of root run fine.

Unfortunately, I am yet to find a solution: there is nothing in `/etc/fstab` to suggest `/home` is mounted as `noexec`:

```
/userdata/user-data /home none bind 0 0
```

I have even tried remounting it explicitly as `exec` using `mount -o remount,rw,exec /home` to no avail. Will update if I find a solution.

So far the only workaround is to use an interpreter to run scripts (Bash/Python etc.) or `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 /path/to/file` for binary applications.

Minor update: A slightly more elegant workaround is to move the script/application to another directory, such as `/opt`, and then symlink to it. That way you can run it just by `/path/to/symlink`. For example, you could do:

```
sudo mv /path/to/SCRIPT.sh /opt
ln -s /opt/SCRIPT.sh /path/to
```

Then you could just type `/path/to/SCRIPT.sh` to run it.

---

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION**

Found out the problem is to do with the apparmor security profile for the terminal app. See my question and answer here: [Ubuntu touch – executable files won't launch in /home directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646655/ubuntu-touch-executable-files-wont-launch-in-home-directory)

Comment: Thanks a million was wondering why I couldn't get node running ...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the shabang line to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

rather than

```
#!/bin/sh
```

This will default the interpreter to bash, rather than sh.  That should be simpler.