# Ubuntu touch – executable files won't launch in /home directory

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-touch, scripts, home-directory, executable

I just received a Meizu MX4 and have already started hacking away at it.
One problem I have run into involves not having permission to run executable scripts and files located in the home directory.

I understand that this is probably a security feature. The problem is I can't find a way to override it. The fstab entry for `/home` makes no mention of `noexec`:

```
/userdata/user-data /home none bind 0 0
```

I have tried explicitly remounting it with rw and exec options, (after remounting root as rw), I have tried playing about with chmod to no avail. Is there a way to fix to this?

I know there are workarounds – call an interpreter/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 to run the executable; move it to another directory and symlink to it from inside home. But I am looking for a way to explicitly run an executable inside /home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer here: [why ubuntu touch terminal cannot execute app](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556041/why-ubuntu-touch-terminal-cannot-execute-app)

Apparently it has to do with the Terminal app's apparmor settings.

Run `` sudo nano `ls /var/lib/apparmor/profiles | grep "terminal"` `` and replace the lines indicated in the link with `/** pix,` (remember the comma, if omitted terminal app will stop working) and restart.